# Configure multiple virtualhosts in apache with different ports

Tags: apache, ssl

I want to redirect my apache server to two different urls. I am creating the two different virtualhost as below.

first virtualhost as below

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>

 ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:5002/app1
 ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:5002/app1
<Location />
      #Options  FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

second virtual host as:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>

 ProxyPass /app2 http://localhost:5001/app2
 ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://localhost:5001/app2
<Location />
      #Options  FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I tried to access localhost/app1, I am getting successfully, but when I tried to access localhost/app2 I am getting **Not Found**

When I do interchange the first virtualhost with the second and second with the first I am able to access first virtual host only.

Please help me to configure two different virtualhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a unique ServerName in each virtualHost. even you can access both applications through a single Virtualhost. i.e

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>

 ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:5002/app1
 ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:5002/app1
 ProxyPass /app2 http://localhost:5001/app2
 ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://localhost:5001/app2
<Location />
      #Options  FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But both app1 and app2 are running in my localhost (locally) with different port